# How to divide .for file on parts with conditions

Tags: notepad++, notepad, wordpad

If we have for example very big matrix .for file 50MB shown down. I have to 
divide it on 50 separated .for files not bigger then 1Mb. How to make them automatically,
not copy/paste manual? As we have example list down, it will be good to divide 
it on the end of some members of matrix, not somewhere in the middle of numbers,
because of easier following.

```
 ...
 A(1,1)=608245.2842 + 0.344804658*X(65) - 10.10795816*X(66) + 7.65
 #7204197*X(67) - 0.471680875*X(68) + 3.555346388*X(69) - 0.94350445
 #25*w(70) - 1.887567575*w(71) - 0.5289184608*w(72) + 0.7835863517*w
 #(73) + 0.7797242472*w(74) - 0.06254543093*w(75)

 A(1,2)=6) - 0.3096263716*w(77) + 0.2442622122*w(78) + 0.39008*w(79) 
 #+ 0.05444760161*w(80) + 2.141140126e6*w(1)**2 - 9868.479006*w(1)*w
 #(2) + 187397.7897*w(2)**2 + 1.326258688e6*w(1)*w(3) - 162807.522*w
 #(2)*w(3) + 244696.3804*w(3)**2 + 495793.6949*w(1)*w(4) + 85100.066
 ...
```

Comment: If you were on Linux, you could use `csplit`.

Comment: @Dennis Windows

Comment: @Dennis Can I use csplit in notepad++ or something similar?

Comment: No, as I said "If you were on Linux...". I failed to mention that this includes installing Cygwin or similar on Windows.

Comment: @Dennis Do you have idea how to make parts? With Cygwin I can? If I will find Linux, can you explain me how to do that?